# Initialize Session Variables: ActionFilter or BaseController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some variables i need to tucked into the session just as soon as my app is requested.
I'm just wondering where i should do this: on an actionfilter then apply the filter to my app's HomeController/IndexAction? or should i do the initialization in a base controller and have HomeController and indeed every other controller extend it?

'#iamalearner'

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do this! do you need this variables for authenticated users? or for everyone?

Comment: there are no authenticated users per se...for a user browsing from page to page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Session_Start method in Global.asax. This is called each time a new session is requested.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["VAR1"] = 1;
    Session["VAR2"] = 2;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is where it should be then...perhaps i should put all the logic in a class of its own and just call it from Session_Start().i'd try it and come back to u...cheers